# iOS - Sending one audio stream to the built-in speaker and a different stream to a Bluetooth HFP speaker

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, bluetooth

I am building an alarm clock app which works in conjunction with a physical Bluetooth device. I need to send one audio file (a song selected from the iTunes Library) to the built-in speaker and a separate audio file to the Bluetooth device (which is, effectively, a Bluetooth HFP speaker) at the same time.

My first thought in completing this would be to use `AVAudioSession`'s new `AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute`, but iOS 7 does not detect my speaker as a possible route; it will detect *either* the built-in speaker *or* the HFP speaker, but it will not detect both simultaneously. Detecting both is required to send two files at the same time.

My second thought was to use `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` (even though the app has no need for a microphone) and to use `overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker` and `overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone` like so:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"alarm"
                                                          ofType:@"m4a"];

NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

self.bluetoothAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL
                                                               error:nil];

self.bluetoothAudioPlayer.delegate = self;

[self.bluetoothAudioPlayer play];

NSError *error = nil;

NSURL *selectedSongURL = [self.selectedSong valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

NSLog(@"selectedSongURL: %@", selectedSongURL);

if (selectedSongURL) {
    if (![[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"overrideOutput error: %@", error);
    }
    self.internalAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:selectedSongURL error:nil];
    self.internalAudioPlayer.delegate = self;
    [self.internalAudioPlayer play];
}
```

After this alarm is silenced, I run `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:nil];` to reset the override call.

However, this doesn't work because iOS just puts both audio signals on the same speaker.

Is there a way to send one audio stream to a Bluetooth HFP speaker and a different audio stream to the built-in speaker?

Comment: This isn't possible with public api as iOS abstracts away the audio system. (how they can intergrate Airplay & bluetooth speaker support without apps nowing about it).